# Как прочитать страницу с cdn?

Tags: c#

Сделал метод, который нормально загружает страницы из обычного домена, а с cdn, как http://cdn.lenta.ru/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml сообщает о 404 ошибке.

Ошибку выдает в строке

```
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Метод:

```
public string DownloadHtml(string uri, Encoding encoding)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;

    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla / 5.0(Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit / 537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome / 46.0.2490.86 Safari / 537.36";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*;q=0.8";
    request.KeepAlive = true;

    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding);
    sr.ReadLine();
    string html = sr.ReadToEnd();

    return html;
}
```

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, кто его знает? Может, нужен referrer?

Comment: Спасибо, referrer не помогает.
request.Referer = "http://lenta.ru/robots.txt";

Comment: Вы уверены, что из robots.txt может вести валидный referer? Я бы, честно говоря, засомневался на месте CDN.

Answer (score 2):

Если на сервер передавать следующие http-header's

```
GET http://cdn.lenta.ru/sitemaps/sitemap-news.xml HTTP/1.1
Host: cdn.lenta.ru
Accept: text/html,*/*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

то сервер вернет xml с тегами url, loc, lastmod, changefreq, priority.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло это (но почему ошибка 404 была? :-( )

```
using (HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest())
{
    request.UserAgent = Http.ChromeUserAgent();
    request.KeepAlive = true;
    sourcePage = request.Get(url).ToString();                    
}
```

HttpRequest - это класс библиотеки xNet

Answer (score 0):

А еще библиотека http://restsharp.org/ поможет, например:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://cdn.lenta.ru/sitemaps/sitemap.xml");

var request = new RestRequest();

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

string html = response.Content;
```